# Assign value in closure to a global Variable

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I'm woking on an APP which sends requests to a Webserver and receives the answer as a JSON String. In this method I'm casting it to a dictionary, check if the user is valid and then I want to assign the User ID to a global variable. 
My Problem is that the user ID I get from the JSON String won't get assigned to 'userID'.

```
var userID: String!
// authenticate the user by an email and a password
func authtenticateUser(email: String, password: String) {
    execHttpRequest(token: "/api/v1/authenticate/", parameter: ["email": "\(email)", "password": "\(password)"], method: "POST", completion: {
        returnString in

        do {
            let content = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: returnString, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as? [String: AnyObject]
            if let success: Bool = content?["success"] as? Bool, success {
                print("successfully authenticated")

                if let id: String = content?["id"] as? String {
                    self.userID = id
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: You're sure than `content?["id"]` returns a `String` ? Can you add a breakpoint or a `print("id : \(id)")` in your block, just before `self.userID = id` ?

Comment: You are using an instance variable, not a global variable. What do you mean "... the user ID I get from the JSON String won't get assigned to 'userID'"? Your code isn't being executed? Have you stepped through it in the debugger? Have you logged the content object you're creating from your JSON data? You've got 3 conditional casts in your JSON parsing code. If any of those fail because the data is not the expected type, or your dictionaries don't contain the expected keys, your code will fail to set the userID. You need to figure out what's failing.

Comment: I just added a breakpoint and id is successfully casted to a string object and can also be printed

Comment: Where are you checking `self.userID`?  If you check it immediately after calling `authenticateUser` it won't be set, since the network operation will complete asynchronously.  You probably want to pass a closure to `authenticateUser` that does whatever you need with the user id and invoke that from the success closure

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah that might be the problem.. I didn't though of that kind of issues.